# Removal of partial data from dataset

Tags: analytics, analytics-cloud

Say, I am uploading dataset's on a daily basis and if a particular day's dataset is corrupt, is there a way to remove partial data from the entire dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading data on a daily basis, the best approach is to leverage one of the ETL tools that is compatible with Wave. It could help prevent the loading of corrupt datasets and streamline that task. I've pasted the screen grab of partners from the dataset creation screen.

[image]